# How to replace the last octet in an IP adress using Bash?

Tags: bash, ipv4, parameter-expansion

I have a variable that contains an IP address.

```
ip=192.165.12.30
```

How can I replace the last octet with `0` so that it becomes as below?

```
ip=192.168.12.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ ip=${ip%.*}.0
$ echo "$ip"
192.165.12.0
```